# Write one complete row in xslx using openPyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I need to overwrite data into existing xslx file(one worksheet) using openpyxl.I am able to get sheet from get_sheet_names function. Can anyone provide me input to write complete row into xslx using openpylx. I have data into list format. it will help me as I have more than 1000 rows.
I have tried to search but did not find any proper answer(New to python and openpyxl)

```
['0.', '   failed', '   failed', '   failed', '   failed', '   failed', '   failed', ' 3.957e-07', ' -40.0000', '1', '0.', '   failed', '   failed', '   failed', '   failed', '   failed', '   failed', ' 2.758e-02', ' -40.0000', '2', '0.', '   failed', '   failed', '   failed', '   failed', '   failed', '   failed', ' 2.758e-02', ' -40.0000', '1', '0.', '   failed', '   failed', '   failed', '   failed', '   failed', '   failed', ' 3.957e-07', ' -40.0000', '2']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have insert the data using iteration into list and assign value by using row and column